# jquery on hover change photo , on click display description

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have have two divs. i want  on hover change photo , on click display description and to be responsive

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where's your code? Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want toggle image on hover do it something like this:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $('.image').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url(http://placehold.it/1024x768)'
  })
}, function() {
  $('.image').css({
    backgroundImage: ''
  })
});
```

And for click something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
  $('.menu').hide();
  $('.form').show();
});
```

Here is full test https://jsfiddle.net/oxn831xk/

This can help you to start. Add your stylings and modify it how you need it.

For example, if you want different image for every link add classes to them and target them separately etc.

Answer (score 3):

To change your background you can use the hove/css function of jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("your div/id").hover(function() {
           $("your div/id").css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
});
});
```

To do the click part of your website you can use the click function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(" your div/id").click(function() {
       // I need more info to explain this one.
   });
  });
```

can you post some of you code so I can see how you did your code and I can change my answer on this.